# object is not callable in docker image

Tags: python, docker

I am a Python and Docker beginner, hence, I am unsure where the error lies.

Python 3.6.4
Docker version 18.03.0-ce, build 0520e24

This is how the python package looks on the disk:

The structure:

```
python-packaging-dependencies
    jsonops
        pyjo_demo.py
        pyjo_spec.py
        __init__.py
        __pycache__
    LICENSE.txt
    MANIFEST.in
    README.rst
    setup.cfg
    setup.py
    __init__.py
```

The main files are as follows.
pyjo_spec.py

```
from pyjo import Model, Field, RangeField, EnumField
from enum import Enum

class Gender(Enum):
    female = 0
    male = 1

class Address(Model):
    city = Field(type=str)
    postal_code = Field(type=int)
    address = Field()

class User(Model):
    name = Field(type=str, repr=True, required=True)
    age = RangeField(min=18, max=120)
    #  equivalent to: Field(type=int, validator=lambda x: 18 <= x <= 120)
    gender = EnumField(enum=Gender)
    address = Field(type=Address)
```

pyjo_demo.py

```
from jsonops.pyjo_spec import Gender, Address, User

def to_dictionary():
    u = User(name='john', age=18, address=Address(city='NYC'))
    print(u.to_dict())
    # {
    #     "name": "john",
    #     "age": 18,
    #     "address": {
    #         "city": "NYC"
    #     }
    # }

def from_dictionary():
    u = User.from_dict({
        "name": "john",
        "gender": "male",
        "age": 18,
        "address": {
            "city": "NYC"
        }
    })

    print(u)
    # <User(name=john)>

    print(u.gender)
    # Gender.male

    print(u.address.city)
    # NYC
```

On my local Windows/remote Linux machine, I call the demo file
[image]

The Dockerfile

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.6.4

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
ADD . /app

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install python_packaging_dependencies-1.0-py3-none-any.whl -r requirements.txt

# Make port 80 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 80

# Define environment variable
ENV NAME World

# Run app.py when the container launches
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

The app.py file. Here
- Call to /toDictionary works fine(simply returns a static string), provided return u.to_dict() is commented

```
from flask import Flask
import os
import socket
import jsonops
import jsonops.pyjo_spec
from jsonops.pyjo_spec import Gender, Address, User

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/fromDictionary")
def from_dictionary():
 u = User.from_dict({
        "name": "john",
        "gender": "male",
        "age": 18,
        "address": {
            "city": "NYC"
        }
    })

 print(u)
 #<User(name=john)>

 print(u.gender)
 #Gender.male

 print(u.address.city)
 #NYC

 #return u
 return u.gender

@app.route("/toDictionary")
def to_dictionary():
 u = User(name='john', age=18, address=Address(city='NYC'))

 print(u.to_dict())
 #return u.to_dict()
 return "toDictionary"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

Call to /fromDictionary fails

```
ERROR in app: Exception on /fromDictionary [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1615, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1630, in finalize_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1740, in make_response
    rv = self.response_class.force_type(rv, request.environ)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 921, in force_type
    response = BaseResponse(*_run_wsgi_app(response, environ))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 59, in _run_wsgi_app
    return _run_wsgi_app(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 923, in run_wsgi_app
    app_rv = app(environ, start_response)
TypeError: 'Gender' object is not callable
10.254.70.61 - - [26/Mar/2018 17:20:27] "GET /fromDictionary HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

When I stop the container, the stuff is still printed

```
[26/Mar/2018 17:20:27] "GET /fromDictionary HTTP/1.1" 500 -
^C<User(name=john)>
Gender.male
NYC
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you delete all the `pyc` files and try again

Comment: @TarunLalwani Delete ? From where ?

Comment: I am sorry, must have been very sleepy

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is where you try to `return u.gender` in the `@app.route("/fromDictionary")` method. It isn't a string so flask doesn't know what to do with it to send it back via HTTP. You could try encode it as JSON data or another format that can be sent as as a plaintext response.